# String.rightPad() is failing to include padding

Tags: string

I'm trying to ensure that a certain string var is always exactly 10 chars in length. String.rightPad() seems to be exactly what I need but it is not behaving as expected.

```
Integer maxLen = 10;
String fname = 'Jon';
String lname = 'Doe';
String formattedName = '';

formattedName = fname.left(1) + '.' + lname.left(maxLen - 2);
formattedName = formattedName.rightPad(maxLen)
System.debug(formattedName + 'EOL');

EXPECTED: J.Doe     EOL
ACTUAL: 19:10:35.057 (57136000)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|J.Doe EOL
```

Am I missing something here? It seems to only be adding one space after the string instead of the expected 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is working fine, likely the debug output view is collapsing the space characters.

You can confirm its working by adding a debug to output the string size.

```
System.debug('Size ' + formattedName.length());
```

This gives...

```
03:30:16.043 (43091000)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|Size 10
```

When I run thus via Eclipse Execute Anonymous and copy paste from its debug output I get.

```
03:30:16.043 (43165000)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|J.Doe     EOL
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the debug view is definitely collapsing the spaces which are inserted. The reason I noticed this problem though is because it wasn't showing up properly in the emails I was sending out via Messaging.SingleEmailMessage. My issue is that Gmail also collapses these spaces to one when a string formatted with rightPad() is included within an HTML body.

Comment: If you use the HTML PRE tag this will retain the spaces. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp "Text in a <pre> element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks."

Comment: HTML ignores duplicate whitespace by default. HTML emails would therefore also ignore duplicate whitespace. You can also use CSS's "white-space" property if you don't want the text to be in Courier but still have spacing preserved (but I'd still recommend a monospaced font).

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Good point, pre tag also works. However, in Gmail it makes the text extremely [small](http://i.imgur.com/r8O0qFY.png?1). In my particular case I think I'll just need to set font face="courier new" and pad the spaces with &nbsp;

Answer (score 0):

Note, if the formatted string will be output to HTML then rightPad()/leftPad() will not work because HTML ignores consecutive spaces. Here's my solution to this problem.

```
Integer maxLen = 10;
String fname = 'Jon';
String lname = 'Doe';
String formattedName = fname.left(1) + '.' + lname.left(maxLen - 2);

plaintext = formattedName.rightPad(maxLen)
html      = formattedName + '&nbsp'.repeat(maxLen - formattedName.length())
```